# Detecting face in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I'm a novice to Swift Programming. I'm trying to accomplish face detection using core Graphics. So far I have written the following.

```
let ciimage=CIImage(contentsOf: "/Users/me/Desktop/test.jpg");            
let accuracy = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: accuracy)


 for face in faces as! [CIFaceFeature] {

 print("Found bounds are \(face.bounds)")
            }
```

I don't know how to create a cimage from local file.It seems I need to input a URL..
what am I doing wrong, please advice.

UPDATE:

I Have Updated my code referring to the answer provided

```
let userDirectory = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
let desktopDirectory = userDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Desktop")
let pictureUrl = desktopDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test").appendingPathExtension("jpg")

let image = CIImage(contentsOf: pictureUrl)

let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])
let faces = faceDetector?.features(in: image!) as! [CIFaceFeature]
print("Number of faces: \(faces.count)")
```

On execution this does not produce any results.

Comment: @Leo Dabus .. That question applies to iOS .. this refers to OS X

Comment: just realized that

Comment: What is the issue you are experiencing? Is `ciimage` nil? Or do you get an error?

Comment: @DávidPásztor is there a way to create a ciimage from a local file? The code I have written to create the ciimage does not work.It needs to be a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `FileManager` to retrieve system URL's.

```
guard let desktopDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {return}
let pictureUrl = desktopDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test").appendingPathExtension("jpg")

let image = CIImage(contentsOf: pictureUrl)
```

Comment: you should use `FileManager.default.urls(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first` to get the user desktop url

Comment: @techno what do you mean "this does not provide any results"? Is the `CIImage` `nil`?

Comment: Actually it works .. I needed to enable debugging area manually.New to Xcode.. been using VS for a while.So expected the debugging console to be active by default.

Comment: `if let faces = faceDetector?.features(in: image) as? [CIFaceFeature] {`

Comment: hmm.. do you mind telling me how to show the detected face in an imageview ... :)

Comment: @techno Feel free to open a new question showing what you have tried while I convert my iOS answer to OSX

Comment: @techno do you need it squared, circled or just cropped?

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks :) I just need the cropped image to be shown in the image view..

Comment: @techno posted the OSX version of my iOS answer below

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks a lot :) will check it out.Do you need me to post a new question... So that you may post the answer over there..

Comment: @techno its is up to you

Comment: @LeoDabus I will open a new question.

Comment: @LeoDabus Need to wait for 12 minutes to accept the answer...Upvoted ! Thanks .. again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154401/discussion-between-techno-and-leo-dabus).